# How to Exit sqlite3 in terminal

Tags: sqlite3

I have ran sqlite3 from terminal but have problem exiting it.

this is how i have ran it:

```
sqlite3 database.db
```

i have tried **CTRL+C** but it wont exit, i have tried **ESC**, **close()**, **exit()** and it doesn't let me go.

Comment: Pretty cool how they came up with a unique command for quitting, that no other program in the world uses. It's like a little puzzle in the middle of your work day!

Comment: @AndrewKoster And people complain about vim lol. I came here after running `.help` in v3.34.1 then trying to run `.quit` and `.quit()` multiple times with no effect (despite it clearly saying `.quit` on the screen)... at least `Ctrl` + `D` worked. Making a copy of the same db and trying again, I couldn't even recreate it. But yeah, would have preferred `:q` or `ZQ` myself...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Type `.quit` or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Type `.help` to get a list of available commands.